# confirmed but unspent transaction

Tags: transactions

I have a problem that I hope that you can solve.. I have, for 6 days now, confirmed but unspent transaction.

This is link:  https://blockchain.info/address/37gsnq1RYrUQrFy5jJvwUSBJBQYqSGdWnn
screenshot from my wallet link to blockchain:[image]

Please, can u advice me what to do.. I'm a little desperate now, it has been 6 days and stillI cant reach my funds.

Please help,thank you in advance.

RoTop

---

Thx Murch for your explanation..excuse my limited English language.

Thing is that I bought with Bitcoin in that transaction BCCash .. Transaction was made in my Coinomi wallet 11.11.2017 and was confirmed on 13.11. And from that point nothing else happened.
I'M stuck.. I don't have BCoin that I spent and I don't have BCoin Cash that I bought.. 
My situation is not good at this moment..

I contacted Shapeshift exchange and Coinomi and still I didn't get any answer from them..

One thing I don't understand.. Can this transaction be always unspent and have I lost my money ?

I hope I clarified my situation..

Thx in advance for your assistance..

Rotop.

Comment: i didnt get any Bitcoincash for this transaction and in my Coinomi wallet it is still unspend (screenshoot). Em I'm in serious trouble?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be confusing the terms "unconfirmed" and "unspent".

When you create a transaction, you're spending existing *unspent transaction outputs (UTXOs)* on the input side of the transaction, and creating new UTXO on the output side.

Your transaction is *confirmed*. This means that the transaction was included in a block and written to the blockchain. The confirmed transaction has successfully signed over funds to the recipient. The output of your transaction being "unspent" means that the recipient of your transaction has not spend the money again, but that doesn't mean that they haven't received it.

The thing that leaves me confused, is your comment that you were expecting to receive Bitcoin Cash for your transaction. Did you sent the money somewhere in order to trade it? If that's the case, you should ask your trading partner what the hold-up is.

If you thought you'll get Bitcoin Cash by sending Bitcoin to a Bitcoin Cash address, you're mistaken.
Bitcoin and Bitcoin Cash are two separate networks. You'll have to recover the Bitcoin Cash by using your Bitcoin private key to create a Bitcoin Cash transaction.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know what the question is, so...

You sent 
from:154Ky1D5jKLoViPA1ep1FqaxGa8LNWzmJh
to:  37gsnq1RYrUQrFy5jJvwUSBJBQYqSGdWnn

The payment is done and confirmed.

So, the address 37gsnq1RYrUQrFy5jJvwUSBJBQYqSGdWnn has the funds and it IS spendable.  You can only spend it if it is YOUR address.  If you sent the funds to someone else, then you likely know who you sent them to.  They can spend the funds.